# Laravel Collection - Remove Object containing empty array

Tags: laravel, filter, collections

I have an Collection of objects - some of which contain empty arrays.

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#34225 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#34226 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#34227 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#34228 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#23760 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Models\File)#23766 (27) {
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(6) "FileID"
      ["table":protected]=>
```

I could use someones help in filtering the Collection of objects so that the objects containing empty arrays are gone/removed.

So that all that remains are the objects with non empty arrays

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#23760 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Models\File)#23766 (27) {
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(6) "FileID"
```

I have populated the collection using

```
 $things = $foos->get($thing->ID, collect());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may convert it to an array using `toArray()` method

```
$things = $foos->get($thing->ID, collect())->toArray();

foreach($things as $thing) {
   if(empty($thing['items'])) {
       unset($thing);
   }
}

$things = array_values($things);
```

Or

**Using** `filter()`

The filter method filters the collection using the given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test:

```
$things = $foos->get($thing->ID, collect());

$filtered = $things->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return !empty($value->items) ;
});

$result = $filtered->all();
```

Comment: Now I have an array but contains empty arrays still

Comment: `array(0) {
}array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(App\Models\File)#23766 (27) {
    ["primaryKey":protected]=>
    string(6) "FileID"
    ["table":protected]=>`

Comment: I wish to remove all array(0) items.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: Filter method is working, thank you for answer...

Answer (score 1):

Collection Unexpectedly :)  has a method filter.

```
$collection = collect([
[],
['1'],
[],
]);

$collection->filter(); // will return collection with only [ [1] ]
```

This is only if you have a collection of arrays.
If you have a collection of collections you would need to pass the filter function. `fn(Collection $c) => $c->isNotEmpty()`

Comment: Still contains the items with array(0) {
}